How to fix Internal error: Expected value to be neither null nor undefined: functionName when creating an Azure Functions Project?
Internal error: Expected value to be neither null nor undefined: functionName when creating an Azure Functions Project.
I am following the steps mentioned here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/ai-services/document-intelligence/tutorial-azure-function.md
Everything seems to be going exactly as mentioned in the aforementioned link yet still I am getting this error. Please Help.
I am trying to use Microsoft's Document Intelligence with blob storage to automate document processing. As I am creating an Azure Project, I am getting this error. Could it be something to do with the installation of Azure core tools? I do not have much background with python or azure, so it might be possible that I am making a very simple mistake.


Internal error: Expected value to be neither null nor undefined: functionName when creating an Azure Functions Project.

The above error indicates that there might be an issue with the configuration or parameters you're passing during the creation of the Azure Functions Project and also it could be related to the installation of Azure core tools and incorrect configuration settings.

Try to update the the latest version of azure function core tools by running npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@latest command in your terminal.
Ensure that providing valid values for all the required parameters and that there are no typos or errors in the configuration.

I have tried the same steps mentioned in the document worked the function as expected.
Function code:
import logging
from azure.functions import InputStream

def main(myblob: InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

Function.json:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "pavan/sample.txt",
      "connection": "pavanstoragehello_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}

local.settings,json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "pavanstoragehello_STORAGE": "your-storage conn-string"
  }
}

Output:


Make sure to check the connection string configuraion. it would be configured correctly.

